# No instance for Num String arising from the literal `1'

Tags: haskell

```
main = do  
    putStrLn $myLast [1,2,3,4]

myLast :: [a] -> a
myLast [x] = x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
```

When i try to run this code i get this message:

"No instance for (Num String) arising from the literal `1'
Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Num String)"

It runs well when I run with the list ["1","2","3,"4"]. I didn't specify the type but it doesn't work with ints.

Comment: This is just another way to say that a number is not a string, and putStrLn badly wants a String.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"No instance for..." error messages are usually misleading.

The problem you have is simply this

> Prelude> :t putStrLn
>   putStrLn :: String -> IO ()

i.e. that function can only deal with *strings*, not with numbers. An often-seen solution is to first translate the thing you want to show into a string: `putStrLn (show x)`, but actually the combination exists as a much nicer standard function:

```
main = do  
    print $ myLast [1,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 6):

The compiler concludes from

```
putStrLn x
```

that `x` must be a `String`. The inferred type for

```
myLast [1,2,3,4]
```

is `Num a => a` and when you now substitute `a` with `String` you get

```
Num String => String
```

This is all quite logical, except that the type checker remembers that the `Num` constraint originated from the literal `1`.

The message you get is thus just another way to say that a number is not a string, and putStrLn badly wants a string. Or, if you want, that the expression would be well typed, if only strings were numbers.

Answer (score 1):

`putStrLn` has type `String -> IO ()` so you need to convert your list element into a string first.

You can do this with `show`:

```
putStrLn $ show $ myLast [1,2,3,4]
```